# Read file stream (video), then edit it, and finally send it to the user in chunks (Node.js Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, server

So far I finished the read file stream and editing it part, I just need to know how to send it in chunks as a video to the user.

I tried doing this and when I open it on chrome it just downloads a file named 'player' (no extension) and doesnt open anything even if I add an .mp4 extension to it.
And on firefox it doesnt download but it says invalid MIME type.

Simplified version of my code:

```js
app.get('/player', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const readStream = fs.createReadStream('file.mp4');
            
            const editedStream // = edit stream here
            readStream.pipe(editedStream).pipe(res);
        
            readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                res.status(206).write(chunk);
            });
        
            readStream.on('end', () => {
                res.end();
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        };
    });
```

I expect this to just show a video tag that loads as the user watches the video.
Also, I'm doing this because the videos are very large (1Gb+).

Comment: `I expect this to just show a video tag` but this is back end code that streams a video.  It has nothing to do with showing tags.